# How call to main() function from main package is made despite being a private while starting an application?

Tags: go

In Golang, function which is not starting with an Uppercase is a private function that can not be accessible outside the package then how come `main()` function from the `main` package is accessed while starting the application? Is there any special provision made for the call of `main()`?

Comment: This is just the way a Go program works: the `main()` function of the `main` package is invoked. This is the entry point of any Go program. See the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) for details.

Comment: You cannot call `main()` from a different package, the rules still apply (but also because you cannot import package main). The `main` function is not "called". `main` is the entrance point of the application. The main package and the main function are special. The first defines an _application/executable/program_ and the second is _the_ entry point. Like in C.

Comment: @Marc I know main() is the entry point of application. My question how does it possible as it is a private function and get called from outside. Like in Java, the main method is public static void main() that's why JVM could invoke it.

Comment: The Go compiler specifically looks for a `main` function in a `main` package and uses it as the entry point. It does not need to obey the package export rules as it is not the same mechanism at all.

Comment: You are mixing things up. Exported/Unexported (these are the correct terms in Go, not public/private) control "visibility", not "callability". Unexported stuff (not only functions but also types, variables and constants or methods) are not visible outside of a package, they are therefore not _accessible_ but they are nevertheless _usable_. E.g. you can have a package `strange` with an unexported function `func f()` and an exported one `func W() func() { return f }` which exposes your unexported `f`. Calling `f` is simple from the outside: `strange.W()()`.

Comment: But _none_ of this applies to `func main()` because main is **not** "called" from Go code or a package: It is compiled that way that your program "begins" with the code in main.

Comment: @Volker that is not true. In a C program, `main()` *is* the entry point. In a Go program, the entry point is the Go runtime, which starts up the scheduler and GC, initializes package vars, executes package `init` functions, and *then* calls `main()`. But the compiler and runtime face no restrictions regarding unexported names.

Comment: @Adrian I know. But I doubt this level of detail is helpful in explaining that main is not "called" like fmt.Println and being unexported doesn't mean anything for main. That is the reason I wrote "called" and "begins". Note the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main()` is a special case. "Exported" and "unexported" are qualities of identifiers used by the compiler to determine if one package is allowed to directly reference an identifier from a different package. But `main()` isn't being called like a normal function. Your `main()` is called as the final step in the Go runtime's startup process, which includes starting up the goroutine scheduler and garbage collector, initializing package variables, and calling `init()` functions (another special case), among other things.

Here's the [spec explanation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution), here's a [thorough analysis of runtime intialization](https://www.altoros.com/blog/golang-internals-part-5-the-runtime-bootstrap-process/), and here's the [source of the runtime's `main()` entrypoint](https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go#L112).